# Connect to the same $HOME directory with two different users and same authorized_key

Tags: authorization

I would like to accomplish the following thing:

I have two users and I want both users to connect to the same $HOME directory. In this $HOME directory there is also the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file located.

The first user is already able to connect to this directory via FileZilla.

Now, I created a second user, copied the public key from the second user into the `.ssh/authorized_key` file and changed the `/etc/passwd` file to:

```
user1:x:1005:1001::/data/user1/shared_folder:/sbin/nologin
user2:x:1006:1001::/data/user2/shared_folder:/sbin/nologin
```

However, I am still not able to connect to this directory.

I always get the following error message for the second user: `Server refused our key.`

The first user is still working.

Does somebody know what I am missing here or what do I have to change?

Thank you very much!

Comment: By default, `sshd` requires strict permissions on $HOME, $HOME/.ssh, and $HOME/.ssh/*. Everything has to be owned by the connecting user and cannot be group writable.  Check out `StrictModes` in sshd_config